# get octet value in imap session

Tags: python, imap

In a telnet session for imap, how can I calculate the value for octet to be passed in the search command. for example:

```
telnet 0 <port for imap>
. login <user> <paswd>
.  select <folder>
. search charset utf-8 body {<octet value>}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[INTERNET MESSAGE ACCESS PROTOCOL - VERSION 4rev1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501.txt)

**4. Data Formats**

IMAP4rev1 uses textual commands and responses.
Data in IMAP4rev1 can be in one of several forms: atom, number, **string**,   parenthesized list, or NIL.

**4.3. String**

A string is in one of two forms: either **literal** or quoted string. A literal is a sequence of zero or more octets (including CR and LF), prefix-quoted with an octet count in the form of an open brace ("{"), the number of octets, close brace ("}"), and CRLF.

In short, the number inside `{}` is the number of bytes(octets) or size of data which will be send from client to server.

For example: Suppose a mail needs to be stored in Sent folder via IMAP `APPEND` command.

**A003 APPEND "Sent" (\Seen) "24-Oct-2016 14:16:00 +0530" {311}**

```
Date: Mon, 24 Oct 2016 14:16:00 +0530 (IST)
From: Fred Foobar <foobar@Blurdybloop.COM>
Subject: afternoon meeting
To: mooch@owatagu.siam.edu
Message-Id: <B27397-0100000@Blurdybloop.COM>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: TEXT/PLAIN; CHARSET=US-ASCII

Hello Jo2, do you think we can meet at 3:30 tomorrow?
```

Therefore, `{311}` is the size of mail.